# How to encapsulate some cucumber steps in one step? or in a parameter? or in tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, cucumber, cucumberjs

Is there any possibility to call inside a scenario another scenario using tags?
How to encapsulate some cucumber steps in one step? or in a parameter? or in tag?

Eq.

```
@payload_car
Scenario: Populate Car payload 
      Given the user "x" populate the car payload
      When the following information about car are introduced: type "Tesla", color "red", length "4.5m" 
      Then the Payload Car is populated

@car
Scenario: Select car
      Given the user "y" is logged
      When the user select the car "Tesla"
      And populate the payload car @payload_car
      Then the selected car contains all the details
```

Is it possible to call the scenario @payload_car when the @car scenario is called?
I mention that the scenario above is fictiv just to be more explicit...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'd want to reuse those steps/scenarios:

you might be able to achieve the desired behaviour by doing the following:

- You can pull the common behaviour in a Background (https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background) (like the login)
- And then leverage the capability of Scenario outlines (https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline), to test every combination that would lead to your Then steps.

But maybe I'm assuming wrong, can you give us a little more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't want to have a big scenario, I want to build a scenario from other scenarios.
And the small scenarios to be reusable for another combination. Using Background all the scenarios call the background, even if there's no need.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot call a scenario from another scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I managed to call another test, like the above example, but the problem is that another instance is created,                                                                                                                 let command =" /node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js  --tags \"@${tag}\"` 
let output = execSync(command, { encoding: 'utf-8' });